# How to Store Images into Specified Collections in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, gridfs

I know it is possible to save binary files into using MongoDB using the "mongofiles" utility.

Is there any way to store Images into a specified collection, not in db.fs.files?

I want to create an users collection which is using to store user details along with their profile pic like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "USR_1",
    "username"  : "willsmith123",
    "firstname" : "will",
    "lastname"  : "smith",
    "status"    : "ACTIVE",
    "image"     : { 
             "_id"        : ObjectId("558be8062f194d2587000001")
             "chunkSize"  : 261120,
             "uploadDate" : ISODate("2015-06-25T10:20:47.105Z"),
             "length"     : 25038,
             "md5"        : "b1d38a0b2ccde6da71fd6ae8fe2f637f",
             "filename"   : "mylogo.png"
                  }
}
```

How can I have a collection like this, which maintain relation between users and their images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Note:

Database is for data

FileSystem for files

#### Choice Matters

Use [GridFs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/) or else use the below stuff

Instead of saving the embedded document

```
         "image"     : { 
              "chunkSize"  : 261120,
              "uploadDate" : ISODate("2015-06-25T10:20:47.105Z"),
              "length"     : 25038,
              "md5"        : "b1d38a0b2ccde6da71fd6ae8fe2f637f",
              "filename"   : "mylogo.png"
          }
```

Just save the reference of the image as below

```
{
   "_id" : "USR_1",
   "username"  : "willsmith123",
   "firstname" : "will",
   "lastname"  : "smith",
   "status"    : "ACTIVE",
   "imageRef"     : "unique id (objectID)"
}
```

Use the `imageRef` to get or set the image.

Answer (score 0):

2. When you upload image , writestream create image
       id. At the same time , you can't save image id to another
       collection.
3. If you create custom id, it's not safe and problem for
           many images.
4. You can save image info in the document ***files.metadata***

Comment: In general, avoid arguing for or against other answers' validity. Instead, argue against *the kind of idea that happens to be represented in those answers*. So simply explain the misconception, the reason it's wrong, and the truth. (This is especially important, as your answer may be left as the only one, and can very easily change ordering.)